# In TypeScript lib.d.ts, why not specify the union type ("_target", ..etc) for the target of HTMLAnchorElement?

Tags: typescript

I found the target of HTMLAnchorElement here
https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/ff75b8a180ac69f5d22c079ae053e4b8db29a307/lib/lib.dom.d.ts#L5989

However, it was not the union type I was expecting, such as "_self" or "_blank".

Is this intentional, and is there any other way to get this exact type?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) I also recommend Jon Skeet's [Writing the Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and [Question Checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). I'm afraid it's not clear what you're asking. The `target` on an anchor can have any string value, it's a window name. There are some special ones, but you can use any string.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I'm not very good at following HTML specs, so I wanted to use maintained types as much as possible, but now that I understand the intention of lib.dom.d.ts, I'll solve this problem.
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#attr-target) on an anchor can have any string value. It's a window name. There are some special keywords (like `"_self"`), but you can use any string to specify your own, named, window.

> Is this intentional...

I would think so, as it's correct for the attribute.

> ...and is there any other way to get this exact type?

If the type you're looking for is a union of the special keywords, I don't see one anywhere in that file. You can define it yourself, of course, there are only four:

```typescript
type SpecialTargetValues = "_self" | "_blank" | "_parent" | "_top";
```